# incorrect log feed in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have deployed a Splunk stand-alone server(also act as a deployment server) with docker and installed a forwarder on my PC, the forwarder management shows that the forwarder has connected to Splunk server. Then I tried to modify `input.conf` as below on Splunk server

```
[monitor://D:\git_web_test1\logs]
disabled=false
index=applogs
sourcetype=applogs
whitelist=*
```

I run `splunk reload deploy-server`  then I can see the logs has pushed to the Splunk server,
however, I found it was pushed to the wrong index(main) and unexpected source type:

```
22/07/22 13:42:40.091   
[2022-07-22T21:42:40.091] [INFO] default - server start at 8080.
host = DESKTOP-**** = D:\git_web_test1\logs\appsourcetype = app-too_small
```

I have never created this sourcetype before, do you know why this will happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-too_small" suffix is added to a sourcetype name when the sourcetype is undefined and the source does not contain enough data for Splunk to guess about the sourcetype's settings.  A sourcetype is undefined if there is no props.conf entry for it on the indexer(s).

The fix is to create a sourcetype stanza in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/props.conf on the Splunk server.  It should look something like this:

```
[applogs]
TIME_PREFIX = ^
TIME_FORMAT = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N
MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD = 23
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
TRUNCATE = 10000
EVENT_BREAKER_ENABLE = true
EVENT_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)
```

The most likely reason why the logs are in the wrong index is the specified index doesn't exist.  It's not enough to put `index=applogs` in inputs.conf.  The same index name must be present in indexes.conf on the indexer(s).  On a standalone server the index can be created in the UI at Settings->Indexes.